# Setting wp_enqueue_script correctly

Tags: javascript, scripts

I am trying to include my own scripts in a child theme I set up.

I have the following in functions.php:

```
function custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'custom_js.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_configurator_css', 'custom_scripts', 10 );
```

but for some reason it isn't showing up in the scripts area within the page source.

I tried placing the custom_js.js file in the following paths:

```
/custom_js.js (root)
/wp-includes/js/custom_js.js 
/wp-content/themes/oceanwp-child/custom_js.js
```

but haven't had any luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `add_action` has incorrect parameters. Use this code

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts', 10 );
```

Also, you must prefix filename with `/`, so correct function code is

```
function custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom_js.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false );
}
```

Comment: Ok, great. Thank you. And may I ask if that is the correct path? The custom_js.js file is currently located in /wp-content/themes/oceanwp-child/custom_js.js and doesn't seem to be having any effect on the page when it loads. Although I do now see it in the page source. Thanks

Comment: See updated answer.